# Write rawQuery with Java to stop sql injection

Tags: android, sqlite, data-binding, prepared-statement

I am trying to prove that my current code stops prevents sql injection. At the same time I am trying to learn to write a rawQuery that uses ? for a place holder.
My Table is as follows below

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "masterPW";
public static final String Col_ID = "ID";
public static final String Col_MPW = "mpw";
```

When the MainActivity starts it checks to see if the Col_MPW has data or not by calling the onLoad method that goes to DBHelper Class code below

```
    private void onLoad(){

    dbHelper = new DBHelper( this );
    str = dbHelper.getCol_MPW();
    // Line of code above calls getCol_MPW method in DBHelper
    // And DBHwlper RETURNS str Variable with the Master Password
    //============================================================
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        etPW.requestFocus();
        btnSave.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        System.out.println( "I am NULL" );
    } else {
        setTitle( "Enter Password "+str );
        tvCPW.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
        etCPW.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
        btnSave.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
        btnEnter.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        System.out.println( "Im NOT NULL "+str );
    }
}
```

Ok so now we will say the password has been created and when the user enters the password to go to the next activity we call the onLoad grab the value in the TABLE and return it to the MainActivity and preform validation
the code below is in the DBHelper and returns a string for validation

```
    public String getCol_MPW(){
    String str = null;
    db = getReadableDatabase();

    String q = "SELECT mpw FROM masterPW";
    //String q = "SELECT * FROM masterPW";
    //String ov = etPW.getText().toString();
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT mpw "+"FROM  masterPW"+"WHERE mpw = ? ",new String[]{ov};
    // The line of  CODE above  fails even when I  replase ov with the PASSWORD
    //=================================================================
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_MPW));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return str;
}
```

The str that is returnd to the MainActivity is then validated with this code

```
    public void onEnter(View view) {

    // Will use REGEX here so matches is ok
    // But with NO REGEX -> MUST <- use equals

    //if (str.matches( etPW.getText().toString().trim() )) {
        if(str.equals(etPW.getText().toString().trim())){
        etPW.setText( "" );
        str = "";
        Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, PageTwo.class );
        startActivity( intent );
    } else {
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        etPW.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

My Code in DBHelper  public String getCol_MPW() has some of my non productive attempts at NON sql injection code commented out. That said I have also tried various sql injection techniques to get past my validation none would work.
So I would still like to have some guidance on how to implement better rawQuery methods to prevent sql injection? After the password I need to add other data to the database. I have looked at prepared statements and binding but if I can not implement this with a table that has only one row ever I see no point in going further

Comment: Why, exactly, are you worrying so much about SQL injection attacks? Your input is coming from the user. It is the user's device and the user's database. If the user wants to execute [a Little Bobby Tables attack](https://xkcd.com/327/) against the user's own database, why do you care? SQL injection is a major issue when the input is coming *from other systems*, such as via a Web interface. BTW, the reason why your code fails is because you do not have any whitespace between the table name and the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You are using prepared statement, which were designed with injection prof and inefficiency in mind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). You code should be protected from injections.

Comment: @CommonsWare My Bad this is a embedded app only on a phone or tablet I am not sure how secure that whole concept is I will rewrite my WHERE clause and because I use a string to make my query is that the same as a prepared statement ?